# Change Windows 'List separator' using Power Shell

Tags: windows, powershell, regional-settings

often I have to change some Windows regional settings and I'm using PowerShell to do that, but the 'List separator' is the only field I didn't find in culture object, any clue where to find it?

My code so far:

```
$culture = Get-Culture
$culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = 'dd/MM/yy'   # 'Short date' in 'Region' window.
$culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = '.'      # 'Decimal symbol' in 'Customize Format' window.
$culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ','        # 'Digit grouping symbol' in 'Customize Format' window.
Set-Culture $culture
```

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
After a lot of trials and errors, I couldn't make it work using the *Culture*, but I could make it work using registry (very weird):

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\International' -Name sDecimal -Value '.'
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\International' -Name sThousand -Value ','
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\International' -Name sList -Value ';'
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for:

```
(Get-Culture).Textinfo.ListSeparator
```

Comment: I tried 
`$culture = Get-Culture`
`$culture.Textinfo.ListSeparator = ';'`
`Set-Culture $culture`  but didn't work. Even didn't change that property.

Comment: That's odd, it does for me.  I did a new query after the set action and the object returns with a new ListSeparator.

Comment: Did you use that exact same code? Maybe need Admin rights?

Comment: Yes, I switched it to a semi colon like in your example

Comment: Thanks @Colyn1337, but at the end I had to use registry, `Culture` didn't work properly.

Comment: @GustavoE.Hennemann This link might be of interest to you: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43795